# could you please assist in changing color of main menu in blue

Tags: html, css

I am new to CSS. Could you please advise how I can change my code so that only my top menu comes in blue or some other color but the rest of the menu comes in white color?

I have tried everything that I could but with no success!

navmenu is id of first UL
sub1 and sub2 are classes used for ul. For first and second sub menu.

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }

body {
    font-family: verdana;
    background-color: #ABC;
    padding: 50px;
    }

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #009;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

/* rules for navigation menu */
/* ========================================== */

ul#navmenu {
    width: 645px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 9pt;
    }

ul#navmenu li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    }

ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li {
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 5px;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 3px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #CFC;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color: #FF0;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 126px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display: block;
    }
```

[image of the menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67xWl.jpg)

Comment: do you mean the blue color of the link text?

Comment: I mean blue color block for top menu

Comment: you want a blue background?

Comment: did you try something like: ul#navmenu {
    width: 645px;
    margin: 0px auto; background-color: #00f;
} ?

Comment: The problem is your question sounds like you want the dropdowns displayed in white text on a white background.

Comment: yes...only for top menu..rest in white..

Comment: '<ul id="navmenu">'

 '<li><a href="#">hyperlink 1</a></li>'

  <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2</a>

   <ul class="sub1">

    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 2.1</a></li>

   </ul></li>

  <li><a href="#">hyperlink 3</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4</a>

   <ul class="sub1">

    <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.1</a></li>


     <ul class="sub2">

      <li><a href="#">hyperlink 4.3.1</a></li>


     </ul></li>

   </ul></li>

 </ul>
'

Comment: @Mr Lister  sorry for that...but I mean I want top menu in blue background color block with black text and submenus with white background color block having black text

Comment: @guergana : thanks for your reply ..but it didn't work

Comment: Can you edit the question and paste the HTML in? Comments are not suitable for showing HTML code.

Comment: ul#navmenu li { background-color: #00f; } ul#navmenu li a{ color:#000;} /**this would work for blue background and black text color. if you want to go down and target the children of the first menu do the ul#navmenu > li > ul > li { background-color:#fff; } ul#navmenu > li > ul > li a { color:#000; }*/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, hope it helps.

```css
ul#navmenu {
    width: 645px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}


ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 9pt;    
    }

ul#navmenu li {
    width: 125px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
    }

ul#navmenu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    color:#fff;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li a,
ul#navmenu .sub2 li a
 { 
    background:#fff; 
    color:#000;
}

ul#navmenu .sub1 li {
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 a {
    margin-top: 5px;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub2 a {
    margin-left: 3px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover > a {
    background-color: #CFC;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover a:hover {
    background-color: #FF0;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub1 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    left: 0px;
    }

ul#navmenu ul.sub2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 126px;
    }

ul#navmenu li:hover .sub1 {
    display: block;
    }

ul#navmenu .sub1 li:hover .sub2 {
    display: block;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your exact mark-up, I could assume that this will work:

```
ul#navmenu {
    width: 645px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

ul#navmenu, ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
ul.sub1, ul.sub2 {
    background-color: #FFF;
}
```

Please post your HTML and I will confirm.

Thanks